# If a product is bounded in probability, are the terms also bounded in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics

Suppose we have $a_n$ and $b_n$ random variables such that $a_n \times b_n = Op(n^{k})$  for $n \to \infty$.

We have $a_n = C + op(1)$, with $C \ne 0$.

Intuition tells me $b_n =  Op(n^{k})$ , but how do I prove this?

Comment: I am not familiar with $Op(n^{k})$ notation but don't we have $a_n=C+Op(1)$ if $a_n=0$ for all $n$ and $C=1$? In that case $\{b_n\}$ can be anything.

Comment: $c_n = op(n^k)$ if for every $\delta > 0$, we have $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|c_n| n^{-k} > \delta) = 0$

Comment: $c_n = Op(n^k)$ if  $\lim\limits_{M \to \infty} \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|c_n| n^{-k}>M) = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume, without loss of generality, that C > 0.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta = C/2$ there is a $N_a$ such that for $n > N_a$,

$P( |a_n|> C - \delta  ) < \epsilon/2$.

Then, for $n > N_a$

$P( n^{-k}|a_n b_n| > M ) > P( n^{-k}  |b_n| > 2 M / C  ) = P( n^{-k}  |b_n| > M_* )$

with $M_* = 2 M /C $

hence if $b_n$ isn't $Op(n^k)$ the right side doesn't go less than an $\epsilon/2$ no matter the $M$, which would implies that $a_n \times b_n \ne Op(n^{k})$